# .glusterfs folder is huge whereas my regular data is smaller

Tags: glusterfs

I'm using GlusterFS 3.7.6 and recently my disk space has been steadily increasing.  Upon investigating my .glusterfs is huge (514 GB), whereas my total data sits at (324 GB).

Why is my .glusterfs folder so large?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Our Gluster bricks are 30G, of which 24G disk space is in use, and the .glusterfs folder takes up 13G of that 24G.

Answer (score 1):

@Mave

The issue was that glusterfs keeps a copy of deleted files in the .trashcan directory.  I had to write a cronjob to issue a 'delete' command on the folder which deletes the contents within (the folder itself won't be deleted).

But since this folder is for self-heal and rebalance, your choice of what get's deleted should be carefully thought about.

Here's a link for more info: [GlusterFS Trash](https://docs.gluster.org/en/v3/Administrator%20Guide/Trash/)